# Mysql select with in clause does not use index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a contacts table which has a primary key of id. It also has a secondary index idx_id_del_user (id, deleted, user_id).

The following query uses the index and therefore is very fast -

```
select id
from jts_contacts
where id = '00000402-25c8-7375-e3df-4ec5b66de11d'
and deleted = 0;
```

1 row fetched in 0.0098s

However when I use the in clause the outer query goes into a full table scan. I am expecting it to use either the primary key or the idx_id_del_user.

```
select  *
from jts_contacts FORCE INDEX (idx_id_del_user)
where id in
(select id
from jts_contacts
where id = '00000402-25c8-7375-e3df-4ec5b66de11d')
and deleted = 0
```

1 row fetched in 9s

Explain plan -

```
id, select_type,          table,         type, possible_keys,                 key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1, 'PRIMARY',            'jts_contacts', 'ALL', '',                           '',   '',     '', 1127275, 'Using where'
2, 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'jts_contacts', 'const', 'PRIMARY,idx_id_del_user', 'PRIMARY', '108', 'const', 1, 'Using index'
```

This table has 1.2 million records and the table was analyzed. I have tried it without the FORCE INDEX option, but it is still not using the index. Any suggestions on making this query faster?

---

Caveat: using a join instead of the in clause will work, however since this is a generated query from a existing product - it cannot be changed to use joins.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, `IN` goes through all of the matching records and compares them to the values in the clause, one row at a time.

So, the best you can do is use an index on `deleted` and you'll only be going through the records where `deleted = 0`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that as well. However deleted only has two vlaues 0 and 1 (it is not very selective). I actually increases the response time to 12s.  I agree with the answer, however it does not work since the index on deleted is not very selective.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, and after reading Marcus Adams' post, I've thought of something I've learned from running an UPDATE on a table, based on data from that same table: create a derived table first, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jts_contacts WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM
    (SELECT id FROM jts_contacts WHERE id = '00000402-25c8-7375-e3df-4ec5b66de11d')
temp)
AND deleted = 0
```

This will first fetch the complete result from the inner query into the derived `temp` table and then run the outer query based on that.

This pattern increased the speed of my similar queries from minutes to less than a second. I kid you not.